# Is it possible to open .iso file in emacs dired?

Tags: dired

When I open `.iso` file in `dired`, I have to mount it a temp folder

```
mount -t iso9660 foo.iso temp
```

then navigate to that folder, read the files.

Is it possible to open `.iso` file in dired directly? (possibly dired create a temp folder?)

Comment: I suspect that the answer is that it's possible in principle, but no-one has implemented it yet. If anyone feels like trying, `tar-mode.el` might be a good starting point.

Comment: It might be possible with only a slight modification of `tar-mode.el`, actually.

Answer (score 4):

My Linux machine has the command [`iso-info`](http://www.manpager.com/linux/man1/iso-info.1.html) available, which is a part of package `libcdio`. It supports the option `-l` which gives *output similar to 'ls -lR' for an ISO 9660 fs*.

Run `iso-info -l some.iso` via <kbd>M-!</kbd> and then switch the output buffer into [`dired-virtual-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/dired-x/Virtual-Dired.html).